# Deploy MVC 6 app in IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2015RC and I created a simple MVC 6 application, but when I try to publish it I don't see the option to deploy it to IIS, I see the options Microsoft Azure Web App, Import and File System, I tried the File System but It looks like it is more for creating stand alone applications to be launched from a console, now, when debugging I can select IIS Express or the web command, there is no IIS option, so the question is, how can I deploy the MVC6 web application I created to IIS?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

File System publish is actually exactly what you want; All DNX applications are stand-alone, whether for ASP.NET 5 or a console app.

When you publish to the File System, you get a few folders; the `wwwroot` (assuming you kept the default in your `project.json`) folder is where IIS should point. The web.config in that folder is generated for you automatically assuming you keep everything else where it is.

For what it's worth, the [official documentation will probably be here](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html), once it's written. Also, on Stack Overflow, [ASP.NET 5 project hosting on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27325264/195653) probably has some useful information, though it looks like it's a bit out of date at the moment.

Comment: Sure. Make sure you accept answers to your questions that help you!

Comment: I was just in doubt about which folder should be root. So thanks :)

Comment: I have some serious troubles fixing the "Path too long"-Issue,since none of the found solutions work.