# How do I use a Local IIS with .NET Core, C# 6 and Visual studio 2015?

Tags: c#, iis, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, c#-6.0

Previously when working with .net 4.5 and Visual Studio 2013, I could just right click the project, select Web and choose Local IIS like this:
[image]
Here I could select a URL for my application and stuff like that.

However, in Visual studio 2015 it looks like this:
[image]

How do I use a local IIS? I dont want to start IIS express everytime, I just want to build and then refresh the page like I always have done... :)

Comment: I've checked it in VS2015, and I see that web tab looks exactly like in VS2012 and you can choose local IIS in the same place. Maybe you should install some updates

Comment: Have you tried it with a ASP.NET 5 project?

Comment: No, sorry it was ASP .NET 4, when I'm choosing ASP.NET 5 and go to Debug tab my VS crashing :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because in **VS 2013** you're using **ASP.NET 4.5** -or similar- Web application.

In **VS2015** you can also use that one but as you can see in your screenshots that project properties screen is for **ASP.Net 5 *preview* project**
So, for **ASP.Net 5 *preview*** there's no current support for Local IIS.

This screenshot is from VS 2015 with both types of projects:

[image]

You can take a look to the ASP.Net 5 roadmap  here

[**ASP.NET 5 Schedule and Roadmap**](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap)

As a Workaround you can follow the '*manual steps*' listed in this other stackoverflow post 
[**ASP.NET 5 project hosting on IIS**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27539895/793085)

Comment: Thanks man. Do you know where I can read more about support for Local IIS/when it will be available?

Comment: @JuanK Wow..I didnt know that..!! +1

Comment: Thanks, I will accept your answer. Right now, it's not possible to use Local IIS with ASP.NET 5.

Comment: As a workaround you can follow the 'manual steps ' listed in this other stackoverflow post http://stackoverflow.com/a/27539895/793085

Comment: I'm using VS2015 Enterprise FULL version and it still have the same properties page for ASP.NET 5 project as shown in screen 1 by @JuanK. Local IIS option not available.