# Launch ASP.NET website without debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In the default structure of ASP.NET 4.6.1 I was able, to set the IIS to run directly an application without the need of debugging or publishing it. But on ASP.NET 5 I couldn't manage to do so. I have tried to point the IIS to the wwwroot of the project and to enable "Produce outputs on build", but when i want to access the application I only get the following error:

```
HTTP-Fehler 502.3 - Bad Gateway
There was a connection error while trying to route the request.
```

Does anyone have experience with this or had a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

it's not available for right now , to do it we still need for IIS 10  but you can still do it with some trick check link below

[your answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27325264/asp-net-5-project-hosting-on-iis)

Comment: That's sadly not what I wanted as that is the long and dirty way to do it. But even with IIS 10 it's not possible if I'm not wrong as I tested it on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Okay as I wasn't able to find any way to get this working, i spotted a little icon on top right next to "IIS Express" or "web", which is called "View in Browser".

Now you just need to go to the project's preferences, select Debug and choose IIS Express from the profile dropdown. Make sure, the checkbox at "Launch URL" is set and specify a App URL (Sometimes port 80 won't wor, so just choose any other one, for example localhost:5324) and then click on the icon like in the screenshot. Then you don't have to deploy the project or start debugging to see the project in action. Hopefully, this will be helpful to some of you.

[image]