# Publish Web Service - Web API 2 on IIS

Tags: web-services, iis-7, asp.net-web-api2, publish

I want to publish a Web Service created with Web Api 2 MVC5(this is my first time), in IIS 7. Following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_2GtWL4UXBU), after doing "Publish..." in Visual Studio for my web service, this is my publish folder: [Publish folder image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M20LA.png)

Then I tried to Add a Web Site in the IIS Express exactly as it is done in the tutorial, and after that when I Browse it, I got a HTTP 403 Error.

Also, I test with Fiddler a POST method and I get 404 `HttpNotFound`.

**Update:** Additionally, I follow step by step [this tutorial](http://dotnetmentors.com/web-api/host-asp-net-web-api-in-iis-using-visual-studio-publish.aspx) and when I tried to test the route mapping, I get 404 `HttpNotFound`.

What am I missing?
Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Requisites

Also verify that you have installed *HTTP Platform Handler version 1.2*. You can download it [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html#install-the-http-platform-handler)

### Publishing

When publishing your site be sure to point into *wwwroot folder* ([check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27539895/1413537))

Answer (score 0):

First check that .Net 4.5 is installed on server or not .Please use aspnet_regiis -i command to install .Net4.5 server on iis.Also make sure there is an entry in your web config

```
<system.webServer>
```

Comment: I checked and verified that I have .NET 4.5 installed and also the entry in web config, do you have any other suggestions?